# Does anyone know an iPhone app that replicates the 'Find My iPhone' feature of MobileMe?

Tags: iphone, gps, mobileme

### (Non-Jailbreaking Method)

I'm trying to replicate many of the MobileMe functions using free alternatives, like Google Sync for Contact/Calendar/Email. Storage is being handled by Dropbox as a replacement to iDisk and allows me to delete my important data should it get stolen.

However if someone knows how to ping/email/call my iPhone (3GS) remotely and get a GPS fix I would be interested to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on whether your iPhone has been jailbroken.

If you are using a non-jailbroken iPhone, I would say you almost certainly would not be getting a 3rd party application to do this because:

1. It would need to run in the background, which is not supported
2. Apple would reject all such apps as "duplicating existing functionality"

There are some apps that do this on the basis that relies on social engineering e.g the "thief" opens the application, which then updates tracking data.

If you have a jailbroken iPhone, you may wish to look at:

http://old.findmyi.org/ (new website being developed).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same thing, but if you get [google latitude](http://www.google.com/latitude/intro.html) u can do it that way